# How to expose a subset of the public interface to a class

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class - `PluginLoader` which deals with another class `Plugin` to carry out its functions. `Plugin` class uses some functions in `PluginLoader`. Both these classes are abstract base classes so I can't declare `Plugin` as a friend of `PluginLoader`. And I don't want the functions `Plugin` uses to be available in the public interface of `PluginLoader` because they have no relevance to the user of `PluginLoader`. Is this a common problem? How to solve it?

EDIT: Code example

```
class PluginLoader
{
   public:
      virtual void RegisterPlugin(Plugin*) = 0;
      virtual void RegisterFunction(int, Plugin*) = 0;
};

class Plugin
{
   public:
      virtual void Load(PluginLoader&) = 0;
}

class PlugImp : public Plugin
{
   public:
      virtual void Load(PluginLoader& oPLoader)
      {
         //Do stuff
         oPLoader.RegisterPlugin(this);
      }
}
```

Though I want `RegisterPlugin` to be available for the `Plugin` class, there is no point leaving it visible to other users of `PluginLoader` class.

EDIT2: @chubsdad

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class PluginLoader;
class Plugin
{
    public:
        virtual void Register(PluginLoader&) = 0;
        virtual ~Plugin() = 0;
};

class PluginLoader
{
    public:
        virtual void Load() = 0;

        virtual ~PluginLoader() = 0;

    private:
        friend class Plugin;
        virtual void RegisterPlugin(Plugin&) = 0;
};

class PluginImp : public Plugin
{
    public:
        void Register(PluginLoader& oPLoader)
        {
            oPLoader.RegisterPlugin(*this);
        }
};

class PluginLoaderImp : public PluginLoader
{
    public:
        void Load()
        {
            Plugin* pP = new PluginImp();
            pP->Register(*this);
        }

    private:
        void RegisterPlugin(Plugin& oP)
        {
            cout << "PluginLoaderImp::RegisterPlugin" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    PluginLoader* pPLoader = new PluginLoaderImp();
    pPLoader->Load();
}
```

This throws the compiler error:

```
main.cpp: In member function â€˜virtual void PluginImp::Register(PluginLoader&)â€™:
main.cpp:22: error: â€˜virtual void PluginLoader::RegisterPlugin(Plugin&)â€™ is private
main.cpp:30: error: within this context
```

Which brings us full circle. Or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `PluginLoader` interface contains more than just the `Register...` methods and that you want to manipulate loaders via that interface but provide a separate communications channel between plugin and loader you can simply create another interface, `PluginRegistra`, perhaps, which would have the public `Register...` methods on it.

Inherit privately from it in your plugin loader and implement the `Register...` methods as private functions in the loader. Nobody can access the `Register...` methods via the plugin class, they need to access them via the `PluginRegistra` interface and only the loader can convert itself to that type as the inheritance is private.

Now simply pass the loader to the plugin in exactly the same way you do now; the plugin's `Load()` method now takes an `PluginRegistra` interface. No friendship needed. Only the plugin loader can hand itself out as an instance of `PluginRegistra` due to the private inheritance.

An example, as requested, note this hasn't seen a compiler.

```
class PluginLoader
{
   public: 
      virtual void LoadPlugin(Plugin*) = 0;
};

class PluginRegistra
{
   public:
      virtual void RegisterPlugin(Plugin*) = 0;
      virtual void RegisterFunction(int, Plugin*) = 0;
};

class Plugin
{
   public:
      virtual void Load(PluginRegistra&) = 0;
}

class PlugImp : public Plugin
{
   public:
      virtual void Load(PluginRegistra& oPLoader)
      {
         //Do stuff
         oPLoader.RegisterPlugin(this);
      }
}

class LoaderImp : public PluginLoader : private PluginRegistra
{
   public :
      virtual void LoadPlugin(Plugin* plugin)
      {
         plugin.Load(this);
      } 

   private :

      virtual void RegisterPlugin(Plugin*) 
      {
      }

      virtual void RegisterFunction(int, Plugin*)
      {
      }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone explain this to me in detail? :( . I tried to do what it looks like it asks me to do with no result.

Comment: It's not at all contrived. Logically, you have two separate interfaces to your plugin loader, the interface that it exposes to the plugins to allow themselves to register and the interface that it exposes to the world, so implement it as such.

Comment: @Len Holgate: Got it. Thanks. Btw, `PluginLoader` should inherit `protected` from `IRegisterPlugins`. Otherwise you can't pass `this` to a function as a `IRegisterPlugins`.

Comment: I think the private inheritance should work given the example above, you'd need protected if you had the two interfaces inherit, I expect.

Answer (score 2):

**Response BEFORE the OP had code snippet**

I don't see the issue with friends which you are pointing out. Two abstract classes can be friends of each other. There is absolutely no issue in it.

Here is what I guess you are indicating...(just a sample illustratory code)

```
struct pluginloader;

struct plugin{
public:
   void publicm(pluginloader &r);
   virtual ~plugin() = 0;             // abstract
private:
   void privatem(pluginloader &r);    // may be virtual in real code
};

struct pluginloader{
public:
   void publicm(){};
   virtual ~pluginloader() = 0;       // abstract
private:
   void privatem(){}                  // may be virtual in real code
   friend struct plugin;              // friend declaration
};

void plugin::publicm(pluginloader &r){
   r.privatem();                      // use private methods of pluginloader
}

void plugin::privatem(pluginloader &r){
   r.privatem();                      // use private methods of pluginloader
}

plugin::~plugin(){}
pluginloader::~pluginloader(){}

struct APlugin : plugin{
   ~APlugin(){}
};

struct ALoader : pluginloader{
   ~ALoader(){}
};

int main(){
   APlugin apl;
   ALoader ald;

   apl.publicm(ald);
}
```

Comment: Your example works for now. But what happens when you derive from `Plugin` and `PluginInfo`?

Comment: BTW, I think you mean PluginLoader and not PluginINfo?

Comment: hmm so `friend` is totally a compile-time mechanism... :(. Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: Yes. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. that's it. It does not affect friendship mechanism as illustrated

Answer (score 1):

Move the functions out of `PluginLoader`.

**EDIT**: given the vagueness of the question I should perhaps mention that you can pass a bunch of related functions as an argument by passing an object that provides the functions. And you can inherit from a class that provides the functions. And so on.

Cheers & hth.,