# How and why is it possible to change access level of a member?

Tags: c++, oop

I ended up coding (With some help) something like this yesterday:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        virtual void foo(){cout << "A::foo\n";}
};

class B : private A
{
    private:
        virtual void foo(){ cout << "B::foo\n";}
        void DoSomething(SomeOtherClass& o){o.DoSomething(*static_cast<A*>(this));}
};
```

I tried changing the inheritance method:

```
class B : public A
{
    private:
        virtual void foo(){ cout << "B::foo\n";}
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new B;
    a->foo();
}
```

This still works. I expected a compile time error. Please tell me why this is possible and what are the possible uses? I know one use due to first scenario - You can expose different interfaces for different classes.

EDIT:

In the second case, output is `B::foo`.

Comment: Where did you expect the error?  On the declaration of the function as private?  Or on the calling of the function?

Comment: I'm intrigued. Hoping for an answer that would explain the possible usages of this feature (?). One usage might be to force the programmer to instantiate the class B as a pointer to base class A in order to use it's interface. But why that would be A Good Thing, I don't know.

Comment: @PigBen: I expected the error at the definition of `foo` in `B` in the second case.

Comment: @manneorama: Check this problem I posted yesterday. It is from it that I got this one :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084772/how-to-expose-a-subset-of-the-public-interface-to-a-class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ using declaration, scope and access control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084801/c-using-declaration-scope-and-access-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not answer all your questions directly, nevertheless I decided to put it up here for future reference. Also please take it with a pinch of salt as this is based on my understanding of the events that have happened in the C++ Standard world, rather than the actuals.

Read [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403312;jsessionid=BANUY352YZTCPQE1GHPSKH4ATMY32JVN). I don't have the ARM with me, but the article gives necessary details.

Note 115 in C++0x says

> 115) Access declarations are
>   deprecated; member using-declarations
>   (7.3.3) provide a better means of
>   doing the same things. In earlier
>   versions of the C++ language, access
>   declarations were more limited; they
>   were generalized and made equivalent
>   to using-declarations in the interest
>   of simplicity. Programmers are
>   encouraged to use using-declarations,
>   rather than the new capabilities of
>   access declarations, in new code.

In summary:

I think the ARM prohibited it initially:

> An access declaration may not be used
>   to restrict access to a member that is
>   accessible in the base class, nor may
>   it be used to enable access to a
>   member that is not accessible in the
>   base class.

But later on I guess when the Standard evolved [this was eventually allowed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1602.pdf)

Comment: "eventually allowed" well, now, they're deprecated. this answer had a better quote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084801/c-using-declaration-scope-and-access-control

Answer (score 3):

```
using namespace std; 

class A 
{ 
    public: 
        virtual void foo(){cout << "A::foo\n";} 
}; 

class B : public A 
{ 
    private: 
        virtual void foo(){ cout << "B::foo\n";} 
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    A* a = new B; 
    a->foo(); 
}
```

This works because at compile time the compiler can only see that `a` is a pointer to the base class `A` and `foo()` is a public method being called on `a`, which is perfectly valid. The virtual binding happens dynamically at run time after the compilation, this virtaul binding decides that the actual call is to `B::foo()` and not `A::foo()` that is the the performance penalty of using virtualism.

Comment: It's easy to see why it works. But it would have made a lot more sense if it was not allowed to make foo() private in B. So I think the question is, what is the rationale behind that design decision.

Comment: @kotlinski: There is a very famous design pattern called "Template method" pattern which makes use of this rationale. Please check that.

Comment: I don't see the connection between this and the template method design pattern.

Comment: Template method pattern uses private both in base and derived class. That makes sense. Changing access from public to private in this case just seems confusing. Private just doesn't mean anything useful - it's still possible to call the supposedly "private" function by going through the base class.